# Comparing two values and returning the greatest of the two

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two CGPoints that are the locations of two corners of a frame's rectangle.

I need to give separate instructions to them — one set of instructions for the one on top (on a vertical plane), and another set for the bottom one.

How would I go about comparing them and then giving them separate instructions?

Comment: The two points are anywhere in the rectangle?? One way is to compare the points with top most and bottom most points i.e the diagonal points. So if a point is more towards top most point then perform instruction related to top most else perform instruction related to bottom most. Can you clarify more about points?? Comparison is done with the help of Eucledian distance formula

Comment: @Jigar I think you've over thought the question. If one point is above another, it has little to do with Euclidean distances.

Comment: Well, first you have to define what "greatest" means for a point.  If you simply need to pick the largest Y value then that's a trivial test and one wonders why you even asked here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use ternary operators to initialise new variables into a known order...

```
CGPoint upperPoint = ((one.y < two.y) ?  one : two);
CGPoint lowerPoint = ((one.y < two.y) ? two : one);
```

or maybe use fMax / fMin type macros...

```
CGFloat lesserYvalue = ((CGFloat) fMinf(one.y , two.y) );
CGFloat greaterYvalue = ((CGFloat) fMaxf(one.y , two.y) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two CGPoints, if one is above the other, then it has a lower y value than the other.

For example: take two points:

```
CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(100.0, 120.0);
CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(100.0, 80.0);
```

You could write a method:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareYValueOfPoint:(CGPoint)point1 toPoint:(CGPoint)point2
{
    CGFloat y1 = point1.y;
    CGFloat y2 = point2.y;

    if (y1 == y2) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    } else if (y1 < y2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}
```

and call it with:

```
    NSComparisonResult result = [self compareYValueOfPoint:point1 toPoint:point2];
```

And depending on the result, use the relevant point for further actions.

Answer (score 0):

A `CGPoint` is a composite value (`struct`) containing two fields, `x` & `y`.

If you have two arbitrary points then one is "above" the other if its y-coordinate is greater than the other's y-coord. One is to the right of the other if its x-coordinate is greater.

```
CPPoint one, two;

if (one.y > two.y) { // one is above two }

if (two.x > one.x) { // two is to the right of one }
```